# Mandar parámetros a procedimiento almacenado MYSQL desde NodeJs

Tags: mysql, nodejs

La cuestión es la siguiente:

Tengo un procedimiento que me recibe unos parámetros, los cuales me servirán para filtrar en la tabla al hacer la consulta. Si yo no le mando parámetros, pues me trae todos los registros. Si le mando pues me traerá los resultados correspondientes al filtro.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE `pbd_consultar_tbl_roles_activos_usados`(
    IN `_rau_id` INT (10),
    IN `_rau_nombre` VARCHAR (200),
    IN `_rau_descripcion` VARCHAR (4000),
    IN `_rau_estado` VARCHAR (40),
    IN `_inicio` INT (10),
    IN `_offset` INT (10),
    OUT `_cantidad` INT (10)
)

SELECT   rau_id, 
         rau_nombre, 
         rau_descripcion, 
         rau_estado 
FROM     tbl_roles_activos_usados 
WHERE    Concat( Ifnull(rau_id,""), " ", Ifnull(rau_nombre,""), " ", Ifnull(rau_descripcion,""), " ", Ifnull(rau_estado,""), " " ) LIKE Concat( '%', Ifnull(_rau_id, ""), Ifnull(_rau_nombre, ""), Ifnull(_rau_descripcion, ""), Ifnull(_rau_estado, ""), '%' )
```

Los parámetros se los envío a través de la URL de la siguiente forma:

*http://localhost:3300/roles-activos-usados/*  ----- **todos los registros**

*http://localhost:3300/roles-activos-usados/***?rau_id=2&rau_nombre="prueba"...**  -----**Filtro**

En mi servidor de NodeJS tengo las siguientes funciones

```js
router.get('/prueba', (req: Request, res: Response) => {

    const query = `
    call pbd_consultar_tbl_roles_por_agrupador(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, @cantidad)
    `

    MySQL.QueryRun(query, (err: any, response: object[]) =>{
        if (err){
            res.status(400).json({
                status: false,
                message: err
            });
        }else{
            res.json({
                status: true,
                items: response[0]
            })
        }
    })
})
```

```js
static QueryRun(query:string, callback: Function){
        this.instance.cnn.query(query, (err, results: Object[], fields) =>{
            if (err){
                console.log('Error en el query')
                console.log(err)
                return callback(err)
            }

            if (results.length === 0) {
                callback('El registro solicitado no existe')
            }else{
                callback(null, results)
            }
        })
    }
```

```
El resultado de esa consulta es este

{
    "status": false,
    "message": {
        "code": "ER_PARSE_ERROR",
        "errno": 1064,
        "sqlMessage": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?, ?, ?, @cantidad)' at line 1",
        "sqlState": "42000",
        "index": 0,
        "sql": "\n    call pbd_consultar_tbl_roles_por_agrupador(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, @cantidad)\n    "
    }
}
```

Si yo modifico el llamado al procedimiento pero le mando null a todos los parámetros

```
const query = `
    call pbd_consultar_tbl_roles_por_agrupador(null, null, null, null, null, @cantidad)
    `
```

```
{
    "status": true,
    "items": [
        {
            "rxa_id": 2,
            "rxa_idagrupador": 2,
            "rxa_nombrerol": "rolxagrupador1"
        },
        {
            "rxa_id": 3,
            "rxa_idagrupador": 2,
            "rxa_nombrerol": "rolxagrupador3"
        }
    ]
}
```

si me funciona. Pero no sé cómo enviarle los de la url

He tratado con un req.query pero pasa esto, si no le envío parámetros

```
{
    "status": false,
    "message": {
        "code": "ER_PARSE_ERROR",
        "errno": 1064,
        "sqlMessage": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?, ?, ?, @cantidad)' at line 1",
        "sqlState": "42000",
        "index": 0,
        "sql": "\n    call pbd_consultar_tbl_roles_por_agrupador(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, @cantidad)\n    "
    }
}
```

Si le doy un console.log al req.query,

{ rau_id: '2', rau_nombre: '"prueba"' }

me devuelve los parámetros pero no sé cómo enviárselos al procedimiento.

Comment: ¿Está usando [MariaDB Connector/Node.js](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/nodejs-connector/)?.

Comment: Si bien estás escapando los valores usando `?` para evitar el [SQL Injection](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL), no le estás pasando los valores a tu consulta. Dependiendo del tipo de conector que estés usando tal vez varía la forma en la que pasas dichos valores. Por lo general se pasan dentro de un `array`. Si fuese éste el caso, debes pasar los valores de tu `req.query` a un tipo `array`, lo cual podrías lograr usando: [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/values). Saludos

Comment: resumiendo lo comentado pro Mauricio tu codigo queda algo asi : `MySQL.QueryRun(query, [Object.values(req.query)](err: any, response: object[]) =>{.....`

Comment: Fíjate en esta publicación de [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47477346/5503272).
`connection.query('CALL GetStudent(?)',[studentId],`

Answer (score -1):

Cuando recibes el json en Node.js, el objeto req.body.[valor] contiene tus parámetros.
ej.

```
req.body.name
```

si tu mensaje fuera

```
{
   name: "GMG"
}
```

tómalos de este objeto y asignalos a tu llamada a bd:

```
router.get('/prueba', (req: Request, res: Response) => {

    const {_rau_id, _rau_nombre, _rau_descripcion, _rau_estado, _inicio, _offset}
        = req.body;
    const query = `
    call pbd_consultar_tbl_roles_por_agrupador
    (${_rau_id}, ${rau_nombre}, 
    ${_rau_descripcion}, ${_rau_estado}, ${_inicio}, ${_offset}, @cantidad)
`

MySQL.QueryRun(query, (err: any, response: object[]) =>{
```